# get_post_thumbnail_id /set_post_thumbnail not working

Tags: post-thumbnails

i have a field called bookname and based on the entry in that i am trying to check the `posttype = books` and pull out the logoid when the bookname matchs but for some reason `get_post_thumbnail_id` doesn't pull out the id of the image even when its present hence doesn't set the image.

```
$importbookname = get_field( 'bookname' );
$allbookposts   = get_posts( array( 
    'post_type'     => 'books',
    'numberposts'   => -1
) );

if( ! empty( $allbookposts ) ) {    
    foreach( $allbookposts as $importbookpost ) {
        $tempbookname = strip_tags( get_the_title( $importbookpost ) );

        if( $tempbookname == $importbookname ) {                                    
            $importbookcoverid = get_post_thumbnail_id( $importbookpost );                               
        }
    }

    unset( $importbookpost ); 
    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $importbookcoverid );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `get_post_thumbnail_id()` with the `ID` of the post, not the post object.

```
$importbookcoverid = get_post_thumbnail_id( $importbookpost->ID );
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the complete post object to [`get_post_thumbnail_id()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) where as you should use just the post ID. You should also setup post data before using template tags

Please see [`WP_Post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) to see all the available properties you can use in the post object

```
foreach( $allbookposts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    $tempbookname = strip_tags( get_the_title() );

    if( $tempbookname == $importbookname ) {                                    
        $importbookcoverid = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );                               
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

### EDIT

Was a bit to fast, you don't need to pass the post ID to `get_the_title()`

Comment: even with $importbookcoverid = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );  its always empty even though image is present

Comment: Are you sure it is empty, have you verified. Add `var_dump( $importbookcoverid )` just after `$importbookcoverid = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );` to check if you have a value

Comment: i added this line if (empty($importbookcoverid)){    update_post_meta($post_id,'temp',"empty");} where temp is a custom field...it on publish temp has "empty"

Comment: I don't get you on this. Have you done what I have recommended in my previous comment

Comment: i assigned the default template top the post and addedthe line...when i click on view post it does not diplay the var_dump

Comment: plz note- the code i have above is in functions.php

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but please don't waste my time with incomplete info. You have stated nowhere anything about functions etc